# How to fix requests.put method as it is showing status error code 500?

Tags: python, json, html-table, python-requests, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to send a http request from client to server where I am updating the page. I tried testing if my requests.put method works by using a dummy html code and it does. This is the dummy code I used that works.

```
imports requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
pass_string = "<p>This is the updated text for the new page. Created Automatically through script. Experiment successful.</p>"
data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Update Status","space":{"key":"CSSFW"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":17}}'
response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))
```

But once I use the html string that I want to pass for my task I get an error status code of 500 stating "Internal Server Error". This is my code:

```
imports requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pass_string = "<p><br /></p><table><colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th><p>JIRA</p></th><th><p>Type</p></th><th><p>PR</p></th><th><p>Commit</p></th><th><p>Author</p></th><th><p>Date</p></th></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-5742</p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-5991</p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-5971</p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><br /></td><td><p><br /></p></td></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-6200</p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><br /></td><td><p><br /></p></td></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-5608</p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><br /></td><td><br /></td></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-5075</p></td><td><p>Action-Item</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><br /></td><td><p><br /></p></td></tr><tr><td><p>IAP-5757</p></td><td><p>Bug</p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><p><br /></p></td><td><br /></td><td><br /></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Update Status","space":{"key":"CSSFW"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":17}}'
response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))
```

Do note that, the pass_string has been copied directly from the rest/api/content ouput of the website i.e from https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594?expand=body.storage and so there should not be anything wrong with the string but still it is showing that error code 500 and I cannot comprehend why it is doing that.

Comment: I'd suggest creating `data` as a dict and either serialise it with `json.dumps` or passing the dict to `request.put`'s `json` argument: `request.put(url, json=data,...)`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have already tried passing json=data and it gives an error 400 bad request.

Comment: I would at least check that `data` is actually valid json, that is `json.loads(data)` doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @snakecharmerb tried that and no it is not a valid json as I get the error valueerror: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 361 (char 360). I think it is because of the same situation as we have backslash and then quotes and so when we do json.loads the string is not complete as we have multiple quote pairs in the "value" key which ruins the string.

Comment: That suggests to me that the 500 is caused by the invalid json, and the 400 is caused by some other issue with the request.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I figured out the problem but I am not sure of the solution. I am getting an error since pass_string has backslash and then quotes in it. So the json cannot interpret the backslash and we get an error. If I change the backslash to double backslash then the requests.put function works. So what can be the solution so that the backslash in pass_string does not cause the issue. I want to somehow make sure that the backslash completes its required function but also does not cause any issue with JSON interpretation.